# How to handle incorrect system time (offset from the system timezone) on device?

Tags: ios, react-native, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

I know this is a relatively popular question, but the answers which I found didn't cover the following use case:

Let's consider that a user has `Europe/Moscow` timezone set on device which means it is `GMT+3`

But user also has own offset of 10 minutes, so if `real GMT+0 = 13:00`, then `time on device = 16:10`. And this offset could be different: x seconds,y minutes,z hours...

My question is how to get the offset of the device time from the `GMT+0` when you have set personal offset for system time?

So not only the timezone whichs mean nothing when you have incorrect time on device.

P.s. this offset could be achieved on iPhone via disabling 'Automatically defining time' in Settings/General/Date&Time and picking any time/timezone.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Search ´ntp swift´ on internet . This will give you example of how to find the value you are searching for. This [one](https://github.com/MobileNativeFoundation/Kronos) seems interesting

Comment: Also to add that having wrong time set may lead to invalid GPS localisation if you see less than 4 satellites at once.

Comment: @PtitXav thank you! 
so if a user has wrong time set on i.e. iPhone, he will also share wrong lati&long from GPS?

Comment: It may happen. This is because GPS position is used by computing the time that signal use to go from satellite to device. So in case device time is wrong the computed delay is wrong. What also happen is that GPS devices can use more satellites to try to compute device time error . Usually if you see 4 satellites it can correct time. But the more satellites, the best the result can be. The phone may also use GSM tower position to locate or nearby wifi hotspot with much less precision.