# How to get the current time in a specific timezone?

Tags: swift, date, datetime, timezone

I am currently working on an app where I have the necessity to get the current date and time in the Europe/Rome timezone. I have created the following method to do so:

```
static func getItalianDate() -> Date {
    let timezone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Rome")!
    let seconds = TimeInterval(timezone.secondsFromGMT(for: Date()))
    let date = Date(timeInterval: seconds, since: Date())

    return date
}
```

This however won't return the correct value in case the user manipulates the date and timezone from the settings General -> Date and Time and I can't figure out how to get the correct answer. The format I need is something like: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70786159/how-to-handle-incorrect-system-time-offset-from-the-system-timezone-on-device) - still unanswered - with the same problem I am facing here. Is using a server the only option available?

Comment: does this replicate on real device?

Comment: You would need a reliable source of truth for your time. Like a time server.

Comment: Use a date formatter with the timezone set to the desired one to display the date in your app. The date is just a fixed point in time, so you don’t want to shift its value.

Comment: @snksnk yes it does

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateFormatter = {
    var df = DateFormatter()
    df.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
    df.dateFormat = ”yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss”
    return df
}()

let timestamp = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
// display your timestamp
```

In case you your app needs to refresh its view upon timezone changes (hence recalculate the timestamp to display), either react to NSSystemTimeZoneDidChange notification in case is UIKit based or use the SwiftUI environment timeZone global variable in case its view is SwiftUI based.

Comment: This doesn't work if you modify your zone manually. For instance, if you go to Date and Time in iPhone Settings and change the timezone to something else and then manually modify the date, for example by putting it one hour earlier, the timestamp in your function will get the correct date but... one hour earlier!

Comment: I just need a function who returns a Date object containing the correct date and time for the Italian timezone, no input. I tried with a formatter as well but it didn't work out.

Comment: This will always work recreating the dateFormatter each time in your function to get a timestamp. Otherwise you could have the date formatter in your app as a global variable and update its timezone to the current one upon reacting to system wide notifications for timezone changes (NSSystemTimeZoneDidChange).

Comment: @Rexam I’ve modified my answer to also point you in the right direction for having your app view react to system wide timezone changes.

Comment: it still doesn't solve the issue here. The problem is not the timezone change but the user manually changing the time in a specific timezone. I have edited my question again and linked a related (unanswered) question which maybe better describes my problem.

Comment: @Rexam if the user has set his device clock to a different time than the one the time server syncs to that has nothing to do with timezone settings and formatting a date to a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

// 1. Choose a date
let today = Date()

// 2. Pick the date components
let hours   = (Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: today))
let minutes = (Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: today))
let seconds = (Calendar.current.component(.second, from: today))

// 3. Show the time
print("\(hours):\(minutes):\(seconds)")
```